# Python Pandas creating column on condition with dynamic amount of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I create a new dataframe based on a user parameter, say `a = 2`. Therefore my dataframe `df` shrinks to 4 (ax2) columns into `df_new`. For example:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col_01_01': [float('nan'),float('nan'),1,2,float('nan')], 'col_02_01': [float('nan'),float('nan'),1,2,float('nan')],'col_01_02': [0,0,0,0,1],'col_02_02': [1,0,0,1,1],'output':[1,0,1,1,1]})
```

To be more precise on the `output` column, let's look at the first row. `[(nan,nan,0,1)]` -> apply notna()-function to the first two entries and a comparison '==1' to the third and fourth row. -> This gives `[(false, false, false, true)]` -> compare these with an OR-expression and receive the desired result True -> 1
In the second row we find `[(nan,nan,0,0)]` therefore we find the output to be 0, since there is no valid value in the first two cols and 0 in the last two.

For a parameter `a=3` we find 6 columns.

The result loos like this:

```
   col_01_01  col_02_01  col_01_02  col_02_02  output
0        NaN        NaN          0          1       1
1        NaN        NaN          0          0       0
2        1.0        1.0          0          0       1
3        2.0        2.0          0          1       1
4        NaN        NaN          1          1       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vectorised operations with [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
null_cols = ['col_01_01', 'col_02_01']
int_cols = ['col_01_02', 'col_02_02']

df['output'] = (df[null_cols].notnull().any(1) | df[int_cols].eq(1).any(1)).astype(int)

print(df)

   col_01_01  col_02_01  col_01_02  col_02_02  output
0        NaN        NaN          0          1       1
1        NaN        NaN          0          0       0
2        1.0        1.0          0          0       1
3        2.0        2.0          0          1       1
4        NaN        NaN          1          1       1
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot.